# How to store text from field with Google Tag Manager on a form submission

Tags: forms, tags, submit, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to catch email address as a variable with Google Tag Manager (GTM) on signup form submit on http://cloud.feedgee.com/ru/signup and fire a tag with it. On submit, the page is being reloaded.

By now tried to catch it with **Form submission** by **form id** set  [as shown on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uokEA.png)) and a Button click as a **Custom event** with it's **click id**

I initiated a **DOM element** variable with Id of the Form text field (Element Id=ContentPlace_loginEmail)

With these settings in Preview mode on Form Submit, I can not see my Tag in "Tags Fired On This Page" row before page reload.

1. What can be the reasons for this if Id's of the elements are correct?
2. May it depend on the container script location on the page? 
   Now It's located right after the  HTML tag.
3. Can I store form text field in a DOM variable to use it in the tag?

Comment: I saw "catch email" and "fire a tag with it"... are you implying that you are going to send to GA email addresses? Sorry, just wanted to clarify this point. As you should know, Google prohibits sending of any personal information (like email or first+last names, etc.) into GA.

Comment: I want to use email in my personal API, not for sending to GA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the email value in your own API, Google Tag Manager is not the right tool for you. You should only use it to track events that fit under Google's terms of use.

Having said that, when you're working with forms in GTM, hold the `<shift>` key with you click the submit button. If you do that, a new tab will open up, but the current page wont get redirected or refresh. You'll then be able to see what data is being pushed to the dataLayer.

Comment: Thanks but <shift> button doesn't work on my form. Page reloads anyway so I can't see dataLayer.